# How to ignore current month in the calculation?

Tags: r, tableau-api, forecasting

I am using the following R script (in Tableau) to do monthly forecast, using package "forecast". It works without errors but I would like to ***exclude current month*** from the calculations.

```
SCRIPT_REAL("library(forecast);
time <- ts(.arg1,start=c(2013,1), frequency=12);
fcast <- forecast(time, h=.arg2[1]);
n<-length(.arg1);
append(.arg1[(.arg2[1]+1):n],ifelse(fcast$mean < 0, 0, fcast$mean), after = 
n-.arg2[1])",[SUM_RESOLVED],[Months Ahead])
```

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the current month is the last value passed in `.arg1`, you can add the following line before you call `forecast()`:

```
time <- head(time, -1)
```

Comment: Thanks Rob! Just a quick question: I assume "-1" means minus one month as the frequency is set to 12 (i.e. monthly). Am I right?

Comment: You could always read the help file where it explains "If negative, all but the n last/first number of elements of x." So `head(time,-1)` means all the but the last element of `time`.